# WooCommerce: Display ONLY on-sale product but filter by specific discount percantage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have discounted products by 30%, 40%, and 50%. Now I need to create an archive template that would filter out only products discounted by 30% and link to it directly from Product Category list.

All of this should look like `archive-product.php` so I can create a new template `archive-product-sale.php` for the new page displaying that discount.

I was trying to modify `archive-product.php` by adding

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'product',
'meta_query'     => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array( // Simple products type
        'key'           => '_sale_price',
        'value'         => 0,
        'compare'       => '>',
        'type'          => 'numeric'
    ),
    array( // Variable products type
        'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
        'value'         => 0,
        'compare'       => '>',
        'type'          => 'numeric'
    )
  )
);

query_posts( $args );
```

just above `<?php if ( ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_loop' ) && woocommerce_product_loop() ) || have_posts() ) : ?>`

but found out that nothing is being returned. This was supposed to be my first step towards the solution, just to list on-sale products, then to figure out how to filter only the ones discounted by 30%.

I'm completely stuck at the moment with no solution in my mind.

How do I get only specific discounted products to be displayed on a page?

Comment: Considering what https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/ has to say, _"Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible. In most cases, there are better, more performant options for modifying the main query"_, you should probably rather not use it in the first place. Plus, the main query, and the WooCommerce product query, are different things, AFAIK.

Comment: This should really rather be done using the `woocommerce_product_query` hook, see https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-modifying-product-query/ (You will have to figure out how to only modify the correct query though.)

Comment: Correct, modifying `woocommerce_product_query` might be the best way to do it as it is run on `pre_get_posts`, so I'll play around with that option and post an update when I figure it out. Thanks